# 2010 Ford focus failed MOT TDCI

Tags: ford, egr, fuel-pressure

The mechanic plugged the computer and got these faults:

- Exhaust gas recirculation control circuit (circuit hight)
- Exhaust gas recirculation value frozen.
- Fuel pressure control value.
- Injector control pressure sensor circuit (too low).
- Exhaust gas recirculation control circuit low.
- EGR valve sensor circuit. valve stuck open.
- Exhaust gas recirculation control circuit low.

I feel there is a problem with EGR value that causes that causes fuel pressure problem is that right?

- In cold weather, the car starts so hard.
- The EGR has been replaced 3 times in this year.

Any idea?

Comment: The egr valve does not control fuel pressure. The fuel pressure is controlled by the pressure sensor and the ecu. The egr controls the amount of exhaust gas re-entering the engine that is also controlled by the ecu. So, there could be multiple separate problems.

Comment: Which engine do you have?

Comment: Ford Focus 1.6 diesel

Comment: Try blanking the EGR to rule it out. There are special metal plates for this, I guess you can buy them from Ebay.

Comment: Also new EGR requires running adaptation procedure, please verify if it was. Also check the electrical connection. Could you provide exact fault codes as well?

Comment: What I listed above is all what I got from the mechanic. When EGR was changed. Calibrating the PCM was done as well. How can I check the electrical connections?

Comment: Start from EGR connector, check if plug and socket are in good condition, no dirt or oxidation. Then follow with the cables, check if they are not broken, insulation intact, no signs of animal bites etc.